# Images in Apple Mail force a white background because of signature

Tags: email

I'm trying to send an email using my Apple Mail and included a signature that was generated via https://signaturehound.com/.

But when i add this signature, the background of the mail turns white instead of using default user-set theme (mine is dark theme).

After testing i realized images force the white background. I don't understand why. I tried using the exact same signature but without images, and then the background is not forced white.

Can someone test this and answer how to fix this?